# Android Multiple Screens

Tags: android

I have published some apps and today I realized that they are available in the market only for devices with normal, large and xlarge screen... I would like my apps to be available for every screen dimensions... However, I have a galaxy s and a galaxy mini(small screen) and if I use any of then as emulator the app is running perfect. Please keep on mind that I have only one folder for my graphics(drawable). Searching the net, I have found that in order to have my app in all screen size market I should add that in my manifest:

```
<manifest ... >
    ...
    <supports-screens android:smallScreens="true"
                      android:normalScreens="true"
                      android:largeScreens="true"
                      android:xlargeScreens="true" />
    <application ... >
        ...
    <application>
</manifest>
```

Is that right? Should I do it? I would like to have you opinion please

EDIT:

I just tried to add these line in my manifest and I'm getting error when I try to save it. The error is:

```
Multiple annotations found at this line:
    - error: No resource identifier found for attribute 'largeScreens' in package 
     'android'
    - error: No resource identifier found for attribute 'xlargeScreens' in package 
     'android'
    - error: No resource identifier found for attribute 'normalScreens' in package 
     'android'
    - error: No resource identifier found for attribute 'smallScreens' in package 
     'android'
```

Comment: My problem solved. Firsly,i changed from the app properties the project build target  from 1.5 to 2.3 . Then, i added the lines above in my manifest and i run it.I updated in my app in the market and now its available for every device!Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is right approach. Searching on market is based on

```
supports-screen
```

tag in the manifest file.

---

Attributes

```
android:smallScreens
android:normalScreens
android:largeScreens
```

are added in Android 1.6, while

```
android:xlargeScreens
```

in 3.0. Nevertheless, you should have them set to true in your manifest to have seaching on the market work correctly.

---

Make sure you have proper

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="" />
```

This tag indicates minimum version of SDK your application requires. It based on API you have used.

Comment: i m using <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="2" />..is that wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You should try to publish a update for the application with those manifest changes and see if that solves it.

Answer (score 0):

Its all very well documented at [`<support-screen>`](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/supports-screens-element.html) page. So there is no space for opinions here.

And yes, your solution should solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you should add those lines in your manifest file. Also you nedd to add: `android:anyDensity="true"`